# Token with different interpretations (i.e. keyword and identifier)

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, tokenize

I am writing a grammar with a lot of case-insensitive keywords in ANTLR4. I collected some example files for the format, that I try to test parse and some use the same tokens which exist as keywords as identifiers in other places. For example there is a `CORE` keyword, which in other places is used as a `ID` for a structure from user input. Here some parts of my grammar:

```
fragment A : [aA]; // match either an 'a' or 'A'
fragment B : [bB];
fragment C : [cC];
[...]
CORE:        C O R E ;
[...]
IDSTRING:    [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
id:          IDSTRING ;
```

The error thrown then is `line 7982:8 mismatched input 'core' expecting IDSTRING`, as the user input is intended as `IDSTRING`, but always eaten by the keyword rule. In the input it exists both as keyword and as id like this:

```
MACRO oa12f01
    CLASS CORE ; #here it is a KEYWORD
[...]
SITE core ; #here it is a ID
```

Is there a way I can let users use some keywords as identifiers by changing my grammar somehow like "casting" the token to `IDSTRING` for conjunctive rules like this or is this a false hope in not hand written parsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply list the keywords that are allowed as identifiers as alternatives in the `id` rule:

```
id: IDSTRING | CORE | ... ;
```